# matching image in plane/mask to video footage

Tags: compositing-nodes, video, masking

I recently watched [Ian Hubert's lightsaber tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bVUeRIY1E-M).  About midway through, he discusses using a plane with an emission material and a clean plate image (as the color) to animate the lightsaber ignition.

I played around with a couple of different videos I had, and in each case, the plane was clearly visible in the render and did not blend well with the underlying video footage.

I ended up finding [another tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YmrsK5axgVo) that shows how to make a phone appear to levitate through the use of a mask and clean plate image.  I tried this approach as well, but again the mask was clearly distinct from the rest of the video.

I know some steps can be taken to try and minimize the issue--having footage where the lighting/brightness doesn't vary; limiting the number of frames where the clean plate is shown; using compositor nodes to make the mask less sharp; etc. But it still seems like I'm missing something.

As a last resort, I tried an experiment.  Instead of using video footage I had shot, I used screen recording software to capture a video of a simple setup in MS Paint.  I created a large blue rectangle with a small, thin yellow rectangle inside it.  I used a still image of just the blue rectangle as my clean plate.  However, after trying both tutorial methods, I was again left with a noticeably visible plane/mask.

Here is a frame render of the experiment using the mask method (I animated the mask moving to cover up the yellow rectangle, but the mask was distinct throughout). [image: visible mask]

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?  Can anyone replicate the tutorials more or less cleanly?  I'm stumped.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the color management :

[image: Filmic color management]

Blender uses `Filmic` by default but this will change how your footage color are rendered so you should use `Standard` for projects involving video footage :

[image: Standard color management]

The difference between the two is subtle but when you put them on top of each other, it's quite noticeable :

Filmic

[image: filmic]

Standard

[image: standard]